# How to save as and change format file VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code which use **SaveCopyAs** method to change name file and the format to xlsx. My problem is, I think, because I change format type from **xls** to **xlsx**. When I open the new file a error message pop-up : *Impossible to open this file because its format or extension is not valid....*
My goal is to trigger a save as adding automatically a file name (this is working) and change format to **xlsx**

```
Sub Save()

Dim nameFile as String
Dim pathDest as String

nameFile = Cells(2, 18).Value 
pathDest = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs pathDest & nameFile & ".xlsx"

End Sub
```

Comment: You have to specify the file format, examples [here](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s5/win001.htm), documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.saveas)

Comment: `ThisWorkbook` is the workbook that contains the VBA project - are you sure that's the file you mean to save with a `.xlsx` extension? Please clarify what file you're supposed to be working with.

Comment: Just changing the extension does not change the file type.  As @Storax said you need specify the file format.  As a demonstration, create a new file with a macro in it and then save it as an xlsm file. Close it and open File Explorer and change the extension to xlsx and then try to open the file.  You'll get the same error message.  What you've done is to take a file with an xlsm file format and changed the extension to one that no longer matches that file format.  Now Windows is longer clear on what type of file you have, since you have a mismatch between the file type and the extension.

Comment: @ Mathieu Guindon I am working on a xls format which contain macros. I want to make a copy of this file in xlsx because I don't want the new file to include any macros. Do you undestand what I mean ?

Comment: @FrankBall I understand what you mean. I'll go through examples and docs Storax gave. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Sub Save()

Dim nameFile as String
Dim pathDest as String
On Error GoTo ExitErr
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    nameFile = Cells(2, 18).Value 
    pathDest = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
    ThisWorkbook.SaveAs pathDest & nameFile & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=51
ExitErr:
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

This will set both the file extension and the file format correctly, as well as disabling the prompt you'll get when doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies if I'm oversimplifying this due to an incorrect copy & paste, but you need to end the apostrophe marks on your ".xlsx

Another few points to try:

- Use the function ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs instead of ThisWorkbook
- Define your pathDest as the function Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path

Comment: The apostrophe missing is a mistake from copy & paste. But thank you for the advises.